# is there any firebase storage rule from console that prevent download and print pdf document?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I want to prevent any user with my Firebase document URL from downloading/printing my document such as pdf but only to view it. For example, I want to link my PDF file so people can view it, but not share it, or download it, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can control who can access the data through Firebase [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security). But once the user can download the data, Firebase has no way to control what they can do with that data.